# JAVA_HOME and e(fx)clipse on OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-home

I installed the e(fx)clipse plugin on OS X Mountain Lion. When I startup eclipse I get the following error message:

> You are not running your eclipse instance with Java7 or Java8.
>   The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.
>   Make Java7/8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini 
>   to pass -vm pointing to your Java7/8 install.
>   In case you want to turn off this check open your preferences 
>   and go to General > Startup and Shutdown and uncheck 
>   'JavaFX Tooling Java Check'

So I checked the JAVA_HOME and added the following line to my `.profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and my java is now:

```
Kinnlas-MacBook:libexec kinnla$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

But still have the same error message. I also tried to modify my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

which gives me another error message:

> The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk"
>   does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

so I moved back to the original `eclipse.ini` and tried to launch eclipse from shell:

```
java -jar /Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

the launch failed with the following error log:

```
!SESSION 2013-07-20 14:42:49.845 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2013-07-20 14:42:52.305
!MESSAGE [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@5b094702 of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

Any clues? Thx in advance!

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` give you?

Comment: that gives me `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be an incompatibility between the os-x jdk 1.7.0_25-b15, eclipse Juno and the e(fx)clipse plugin. An upgrade to eclipse Kepler solved the problem.